# dotnet build and Visual Studio 2019 difference

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2019

When I create a project using the dotnet build, it stops with an error. But if I build a project with Visual Studio 2019, it is built correctly, and dotnet build also starts to build without errors. What could be the problem?

[image: dotnet build error]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using Costura? Since you seem to be using Fody

Comment: No, I use fody for my in-solution weaving plugin

Comment: It works fine when I build and run the project through visual studio, but it crashes when I build using dotnet build

Comment: If you build with VS, make changes to your code, and build with dotnet build, what happens?

Comment: I built in vs, changed the code, saved it, and dotnet build failed

Comment: https://github.com/Fody/Fody/issues/374 I found this with a bit of searching (you should also search on your own when you post the question too)